# Width issue on body of my page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a horizontal scrolling on my page and I don't understand why :/ I tried fixing it with margin and padding at 0 but nothing works. Do you have an idea what the problem might be. I think I didn't have this problem before adding the parallax effect (I had only the overlay menu div and the button's bootstrap  row) but deleting all the parallax's code didn't solve the issue.

```css
/*------------BODY------------*/

body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
/*------------MENU------------*/

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
.menubutton {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">

  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menucontainer">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <center>
          <div class="menubutton" onclick="openNav()">menubutton</div>
        </center>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="parallax2">
  PARALLAX2
</div>

<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap `.row` has negative margins, wrap it into `.container` or `.container-fluid`.

```
<div class=container-fluid><div class="row"></div></div>
```

```css
/*------------BODY------------*/

body {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.parallax2 {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url('img_parallax.jpg');
  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;
  /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* Turn off parallax scrolling for tablets and phones. Increase the pixels if needed */

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
  .parallax {
    background-attachment: scroll;
  }
}
/*------------MENU------------*/

.overlay {
  height: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  overflow-y: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}
.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
.menubutton {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="parallax">

  <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <div class="overlay-content">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Clients</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="menucontainer">
    <div class=container-fluid>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <center>
            <div class="menubutton" onclick="openNav()">menubutton</center>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="parallax2">
    PARALLAX2
  </div>

  <div class="parallax"></div>
```

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or
>   .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding. **-(Bootstrap Introduction)**

**[More Info](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**

Comment: Much simple, very help ! Thank you :)

Comment: Glad! I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Give "container" or "container-fluid" class to your div id="menucontainer". "row" class has negative margin.